# MapKit for the desktop?

Tags: cocoa, macos, mapkit

Is there a framework similar to MapKit (i.e. that can display maps with overlays) for the desktop. Apple-supported, Google or third party/open-source.

I know of OpenStreetMaps, and I want to know what the options are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at this API:
http://github.com/anagromataf/Map
Is it what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

The upcoming OSX Mavericks will have the MapKit.
Go to https://developer.apple.com for the beta and information.